# How do you find where a variable was last assigned?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, neovim

I am trying to set `g:netrw_list_hide` and it doesn't seem to work. No matter what I set it to in my `.vimrc` it always has the value `,^\.\.\=/\=$`. Only if I source my `vimrc` file again, then it holds the correct value.

How do I debug this? I guess there is some plugin that is setting that variable? Possibly after my `vimrc` gets loaded, so I want to see where it's being set.

Comment: `:vim netrw_list_hide **/*`

Comment: currently not really possible apart from inspecting the source manually. I created this [PR](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/859) which would allow this.

Comment: Won't verbose command help in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine (search, `grep`) the `vimlog` log file for `:let g:netrw_list_hide`.

Answer (score 26):

If you were looking for the last point where an option was set (instead of a variable), you could use the [`:verbose`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#:verbose) command:

```
:4verbose set is?
  incsearch
        Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc
```

But currently there is no equivalent command for variables.

You could inspect the code, or use search in the source, possibly using [`:vimgrep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#:vimgrep), `:vim netrw_list_hide **/*` (as mentioned in the comments).

Another alternative is to use the [`'verbose'` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27verbose%27) to echo everything that is executed after you set the variable. As it will be an large output echoed in the screen, [you will need to save](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#:redir) it (into a register, for example):

```
" in your .vimrc, after you set the variable
redir @b
set verbose=15
```

After the initialization ends, restore the verbose to the default value and stop the redirection:

```
:set vbs&
:redir end
```

You may need to hit Ctrl-C some times, depending on the autocmds/plugins you are using.

Then you can paste contents of the register using [`"bp`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#p) and analyze the "**initialization log**".